# searching in complex mongodb document for values with same name

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I wanted to search in a nested mongo doc for values with a specific name. The structures of the a little complex but the names of the values are always the same. Here is what one document is looks like:

```
    {
        "nr" : "00000209",
        "tx" : "text",
        "list" : [
                {
                    "featurename" : "text",
                    "featuretext" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "featurename" : "text",
                    "featuretext" : "text",
                    "features" : [
                            {
                                "some" : "text",
                                "featurekeys" : [
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekeys" : ""
                                        }
                                ]
                            }
                    ]
                },
                {
                "featurename" : "text",
                "featuretext" : "text",
                "features" : [
                        {
                                "some" : "text",
                                "featurekeys" : [
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "featurekeys" : "text"
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                                "some" : "text",
                                "featurekeys" : [
                                        {
                                                "featurekey" : "text"
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
            }

        ]
}
```

I want to search for a list of strings that in the first two values named **nr** and **tx** and in every value which is named **featurekey**.

Comment: Can you pls explain little more about your requirment?

Comment: normaly i've a list of values ['taxtA', 'textB', 'textC'] and i have to look through all the *featuretext* fields if one or more values from my list are there